# How to remove lines from line plot in Kibana in Dashboard

Tags: histogram, kibana, scatter-plot

I am creating visualisation, based on time series (timestamp) and want to remove connecting lines from each data point. This is easily done in visualisation tab (I just unchecked show lines under Metrics&Axes tab). It seems to has en effect in visualisation tab, but not under dashboard. How can I remove nasty lines also in saved dashboard?
[image: Kibana issue]

Answer (score 0):

Kibana team fixed that in 5.4 version, they create 2 dashboards mode:
Edit mode - with lines.
View mode - without lines